# How to create Django model with django-redshift-backend

Tags: django, django-models, amazon-redshift

I have connected my django app to a redshift DataBase through django-redshift-backend. But as `inspectdb` doesn't work on redshift how can I build my django models that is refering to a table of redshift?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: You may be able to use a postgres materialised view (a view against the redshift data) - depending on your use case. can you explain a bit more about why you are doing this?

Comment: Sure, the advantage of inspectdb is that the django models are being automatically created. I wanted to do the same thing with a redshift db but as it doesn't support the WITH I cannot do that.

Comment: My question was really - why are you creating a model for redshift? django access may well be  buggy (different sql syntax) and slow. what is your use case there?

Comment: I need to use it as a classic DB use for a Django web app, modifying, saving, creating datas

Comment: That is probably a very bad move. you should consider other options.

Comment: Why is it a bad move? I would need to work with the datas on this existing redshift database.

Comment: Redshift transactions can be very slow and are perhaps not quite as reliable as you would need, especially when there is a new query (generated by the ORM) that has to be compiled. Redshift is not built for transnational workload. Another option would be to use postgres and mirror that data (in near real time) to Redshift using AWS DMS.